# Concatenate 2 string using operator+= in class C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I've seen some similar questions before asking, but I'm still stuck at the part of concatenating two strings using `operator+=`.

Currently, I can get separate strings correctly by constructor method. But when I compile code, the line `str[length+i] = s[i];` in the method `String& String::operator+= (const String& s)` shows an error:

> no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘const String’ and ‘unsigned int’)

So I need your help to fix this bug.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
 
class String {
 
    // Initialise char array
    char* data;
    unsigned length;
 
public:
    // Constructor without arguments 
    String();
 
    // Constructor with 1 arguments
    String(char* s);
 
    // Copy Constructor
    String(const String& source);
 
    // Move Constructor
    String(String&& source);
 
    // Destructor
    ~String() { delete[] data; }
    
    /*! 
     *  @brief String length.
     *  @return Value in String @c length.
     */
    unsigned len ( ) const;
    
    /*! 
     *  @brief Append to String.
     *  @param[in] s A String object.
     *  @return A String reference to *this.
     *  @post String will equal the concatenation of itself with @a s.
     */
    String& operator+= (const String& s);
};
 
// Constructor with no arguments
String::String()
    : data{ nullptr }
{
    data = new char[1];
    data[0] = '\0';
}
 
// Constructor with one arguments
String::String(char* s)
{
    if (s == nullptr) {
        data = new char[1];
        data[0] = '\0';
    }
 
    else {
 
        data = new char[strlen(s) + 1];
 
        // Copy character of s[]
        // using strcpy
        strcpy(data, s);
        data[strlen(s)] = '\0';
 
        std::cout << data << "\n";
    }
}
 
// Copy Constructor
String::String(const String& source)
{
    data = new char[strlen(source.data) + 1];
    strcpy(data, source.data);
    data[strlen(source.data)] = '\0';
}
 
// Move Constructor
String::String(String&& source)
{
    data = source.data;
    source.data = nullptr;
}

unsigned String::len ( ) const 
{
    return length;
}

String& String::operator+= (const String& s) 
{
    unsigned len = length + s.len();
    char*    str = new char[len];

    for (unsigned j=0; j < length; j++)
        str[j] = data[j];

    for (unsigned i=0; i < s.len(); i++)
        str[length+i] = s[i];

    delete data;
    length = len;
    data   = str;
    return *this;    
}
 
int main()
{
    // Constructor with no arguments
    String a;
 
    // Convert string literal to
    // char array
    char temp[] = "Hello world.";
 
    // Constructor with one argument
    std::cout << "s1: ";
    String s1{ temp };
 
    // Copy constructor
    String s11{ a };
 
    char temp1[] = "Goodbye!";
    std::cout << "s2: ";
    String s2{ temp1 };
    
    String s3 = String s1 + String s2;

    return 0;
}
```

Another way of writing main function:

```
int main()
{
String s1("Hello World.");
String s2("Goodbye!");
std::cout << "s1: " << s1 << std::endl;
std::cout << "s2: " << s2 << std::endl;
String s3 = s1 + s2;
std::cout << "s3: " << s3 << std::endl;
std::cout << "The last char of s3: " << s3[s3.size()-1] << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Expected result:

```
s1: Hello World.
s2: Goodbye!
s3: Hello World.Goodbye!
The last char of s3: !
```

How can I modify my code to get `s3` and last char of `s3` correctly?

Comment: You try to call ```operator[]``` on the String object s but the String class has no such operator defined. Either define the operator or change the line to ```str[length+i] = s.data[i]```

Comment: And your constructors don't set the value of the `length` member.

Comment: Your compiler shouldn't actually allow `String s1("Hello World.");` to work unless you change the constructor to `String(const char*)` Furthermore you should be adhering to the rule of 5: Since you're defining copy&move constructors, you should also define copy and move assignment operators.

Comment: You've now changed the question so that my answer looks very strange. Please do not do such changes to your questions after you've gotten answers.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry. I've changed back to my original code. Please add your sample code for s3[s3.size() -1]. Thank you.

Comment: @HectorTa Great! Did you add the `operator[]` functions that I put in my answer? If you did, `s3[s3.len() -1]` should work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many of your constructors, you do not set `length` which leaves it with an indeterminate value - and reading such values makes the program have undefined behavior. So, first fix that:

```cpp
#include <algorithm> // std::copy_n

// Constructor with no arguments
String::String() : data{new char[1]{'\0'}}, length{0} {}

// Constructor with one argument
String::String(const char* s) {     // note: const char*
    if (s == nullptr) {
        data = new char[1]{'\0'};
        length = 0;
    } else {
        length = std::strlen(s);
        data = new char[length + 1];
        std::copy_n(s, length + 1, data);
    }
}

// Copy Constructor
String::String(const String& source) : data{new char[source.length + 1]},
                                       length{source.length}
{
    std::copy_n(source.data, length + 1, data);
}

// Move Constructor
String::String(String&& source) : String() {
    std::swap(data, source.data);
    std::swap(length, source.length);
}
```

In `operator+=` you are trying to use the subscript operator, `String::operator[]`, but you haven't added such an operator so instead of `s[i]`, use `s.data[i]`:

```cpp
String& String::operator+=(const String& s) {
    unsigned len = length + s.length;
    char* str = new char[len + 1];
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < length; j++) str[j] = data[j];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < s.length; i++) str[length + i] = s.data[i];
    str[len] = '\0';
    delete[] data;        // note: delete[] - not delete
    length = len;
    data = str;
    return *this;
}
```

If you want to be able to use the subscript operator on `String` objects, you would need to add a pair of member functions:

```cpp
class String {
public:
    char& operator[](size_t idx);
    char operator[](size_t idx) const;
};
char& String::operator[](size_t idx) { return data[idx]; }
char String::operator[](size_t idx) const { return data[idx]; }
```

And for `String s3 = s1 + s2;` to work, you need a free `operator+` overload:

```
String operator+(const String& lhs, const String& rhs) {
    String rv(lhs);
    rv += rhs;
    return rv;
}
```

Also, to support printing a `String` like you try in your alternative `main` function, you need an `operator<<` overload. Example:

```
class String {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const String& s) {
        os.write(s.data, s.length);
        return os;
    }
};
```

[Full demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GrTbW4bG7)

Comment: I can get s3 = s1 + s2, but can't get s3[s3.size()-1] after I created the method int size() { return _size; } . How can I get it?

Comment: @HectorTa You need to add `String::operator[]` for that as I mentioned. I've added an example to the answer.

Comment: I can only get s3 by adding std::cout << data << "\n"; in your operator+= method. How to get it in operator+ ? Besides, after added 2 operator[], I still can't get value of s3[s3.size()-1]; It has no compile error as before but showed empty for [].

Comment: @HectorTa I'm not sure I understand but I added another function that you seem to be missing (`operator<<`)  and a link to a demo program where you can see all my suggestions at work.

Answer (score 1):

For starters neither constructor sets the data member `length`.
So the operator

```
String& String::operator+= (const String& s) 
{
    unsigned len = length + s.len();
    char*    str = new char[len];
    //...
```

has undefined behavior.

Also provided that the data member length was initialized you need to write

```
    char*    str = new char[len + 1];
```

instead of

```
    char*    str = new char[len];
```

to reserve memory for the terminating zero character '\0' because you are using the standard C string function `strcpy` in the copy constructor

```
strcpy(data, source.data);
```

And the class does not have the subscript operator used in this for loo[

```
for (unsigned i=0; i < s.len(); i++)
    str[length+i] = s[i];
```

And you forgot to append the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

Pay attention to that there is no member function `size` in the class used in this expression

```
s3[s3.size()-1]
```

And this construction

```
String s3 = String s1 + String s2;
```

is invalid. At least you should write

String s3 = s1 + s2;

and correspondingly define the operator +.

Comment: It showed error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘String’ and ‘int’) when I ran s3[s3.size()-1] after I created the method int size() { return _size; } . How to solve it? Please checked my modified code in the original post